# Showing $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How would you show that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$, when $n=k+1$ ?

Comment: must you use induction?

Comment: How would *you* show it? Did you try anything? Did it work? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Please use mathjax, this is not your first question...

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner, that is the only method of proof I am aware of, out of curiosity, how would you alternatively prove the question?

Comment: @Gurjinder: Factor $n^3-n$ into its three linear factors, and use the fact that $6 = 2 \times 3$.

Comment: @Rol , how do you use mathjax, I apologise for not using this.

Comment: @Gurjinder: Google mathjax tutorial, there should be quite a few places you can learn from.

Comment: @Gurjinder http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please search before asking: this site is full of questions about $n^3-n$ divisible by $6$, with and without induction.

Comment: @ Normal Human. I apologise, I the future I will look for such questions before I decide to post. Thank you for your feedback, I am a little new this service. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let for $n=k$, the number $n^3-n$ be divisible by $6$ then we have $$k^3-k=6\lambda$$
Now, substituting $n=k+1$, $$(k+1)^3-(k+1)$$$$=(k+1)(k^2+2k+1-1)$$$$=k^3+3k^2+2k$$
$$=(k^3-k)+3k^3+3k$$
substituting $k^3-k=6\lambda$
$$=6\lambda+3k(k+1)$$
since, $\color{red}{\text{product of two consecutive integers is divisible by}\ 2}$ so we can let $k(k+1)=2m$ where, $m$ is an integer. Hence, we get 
$$6\lambda+3k(k+1)=6\lambda+3(2m)=6(\lambda+m)$$
since $(\lambda+m)$ is an integer hence the number $6(\lambda+m)$ is divisible by $6$

Thus, the number $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$ for $n=k+1$

Comment: Cheers, I missed the fact of 2 consecutive integers are divisible by 2.

Comment: That was a really well explained answer, thank you for that one !

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$$ without induction

Answer (score 0):

Using induction:

\begin{align}
(n+1)^3-(n+1)
    & = n^3+3n^2+3n+1-n-1 \\
    & = n^3+3n^2+2n \\
    & = (n^3-n)+3(n^2+n) \\
    & = (n^3-n)+3n(n+1) \\
    & = (n^3-n)+6k(2k \pm 1) \\
\end{align}

for $k = \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Comment: This is where I get to, the fact that something is a multiple of 3, doesn't prove that it is a multiple of 6?

Comment: OK, amended in post.

Answer (score 0):

$n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=n(n-1)(n+1)$ it is obvious that $2\vert n(n-1)(n+1)$ (three consecutive integers, atleast one of them is even), easily you can check $3\vert n(n-1)(n+1)$ too.